# Out Of Range Ex. when converting string to Decimal

Tags: c#, .net

This is very simple , I am trying to convert a string latitude and longitude coordinate to a decimal, my code:

```
decimal[] latlong = decimal[1];
latlong[0] = Convert.ToDecimal(location["lat"].ToString()); // works with "41.6674920"
latlong[1] = Convert.ToDecimal(location["lng"].ToString()); // ex. with ""-87.6831190"
```

the Exception thrown is Out Of Range Exception , I am not sure if it is because the Decimal is too Long, or a negative ??? I don't know , this doesn't really make sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring an array of size 1 but trying to assign 2 elements. That's an error right there. Also, you need the `new` keyword. So just change it to this to get rid of the error:

```
decimal[] latlong = new decimal[2];
```

Comment: Accept your answer, then go to bed

Answer (score 1):

Your `latlong` array has only been created with one element, but you're trying to access a second element with `latlong[1] = ...`

Change

```
decimal[] latlong = decimal[1];
```

to

```
decimal[] latlong = decimal[2];
```

Comment: yea - thanks , shree.pat18 had just said that as well